# Is this a wild persimmon?

Tags: identification, persimmon

Coastal South Carolina, zone 8B:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Larger versions of images available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU2Lp.jpg).

Comment: I was starting to write an answer saying "no," based on the apparently slightly toothed or hairy leaf margins, but then I zoomed in on a photo of American common persimmon (Diospyros virginiana) and saw it has very fine hairs along the leaf margins. This still looks wrong for persimmon, but I can't say for 100% certain. I'm looking at the base of the leaf as well; something about that doesn't seem right for D. virginiana. Have a look at [photos on iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/83435-Diospyros-virginiana/browse_photos?photo_license=any) for comparison.